# How to modify content of json file?

Tags: java, json, import, export, objectmapper

is there any option to modify content of json file? I have 2 methods, export to json file list of different objects, and import from file.

```
public static void exportShapeListToJson(List<Shape> list, String path) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File file = new File(path);

    mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
    mapper.writeValue(new File(file.getName()), list);
}

public static List<Shape> importFromJson(String path) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
    return mapper.readValue(file, ArrayList.class);
}
```

Saved data in file looks like:

```
["Project1.shapeService.models.Circle",{"radius":3.0}],["Project1.shapeService.models.Circle",{"radius":5.0}],["Project1.shapeService.models.Rectangle",{"a":1.0,"b":2.0}]
```

Can i modify that data to form like that:

```
[{"type": "squre", "a": 10}, {"type": "circle", "r": 10}]
```

and still use method to import? What have to add/ change?

Comment: you can read the json into an object, then with MapStruct map that object (tranform) it to the desired object.

Comment: Did you mean to tag your question with `objectmapper`? You can hover your mouse over the tag to read a description (it's a Swift library).